# How can I calculate the derivative of a multivariable function with respect to the average value of the variables if that has sense?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the function:

$$ T=   \sum_j \sum_i ( \vec{u}_j \times \vec{D}_j ) \cdot  ( \vec{u}_i \times \vec{D}_i)    $$

If I call $\vec{D}= \sum_i  \vec{D}_i $  how can I get

$$ \frac{d T}{ d D_x } $$

Comment: Maybe what you want is the directional derivative in the direction of $\vec{D}$?

Comment: Yes. That derivative.

Comment: Calculate the Jacobian matrix and multiply it by $\vec{D}$

Answer (score 0):

Not a "full-fledged" answer, but a direction for calculations involving a linear combination of quadratic forms :

Recall : (see [here](https://math.fandom.com/wiki/Cross_product)) the cross product of two vectors can be written under the mixed "matrix-vector" form :

$$U \times V = [U]_{_\times}V$$

where, if $U$ has entries $U_x,U_y,U_z$,

$$[U]_{_\times}=\pmatrix{0&-U_z&U_y\\U_z&0&-U_x\\-U_y&U_x&0}$$

(please note that the antisymmetry of this matrix accounts for the antisymmetry of the cross product).

Let us write initial expression with matrix notations :

$$T=   \sum_j \sum_i (\vec{D}_j  \times u_j)^T   ( \vec{D}_i \times u_i )$$

(where the $u_i$ and $u_j$ are column vectors)

can be transformed into :

$$T=   \sum_j \sum_i ([\vec{D}_j]_{_\times}u_j)^T( [\vec{D}_i]_{_\times}u_i)$$

$$T=   \sum_j \sum_i u_j^T\left([\vec{D}_j]^T_{_\times} [\vec{D}_i]_{_\times}\right)u_i$$

which, as a sum of quadratic expressions, gives a more handy way for further calculations.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is interesting. I was thinking for example if $$f(x_1,x_2,..., x_n)$$ And then we define $x= (x_1+x_2+...+x_n)$ if it has sense to say that $$\frac{d f}{dx} = \frac{1}{N} \frac{d f(x,...,x)}{dx} $$  But thats where I am confused

Comment: Maybe, as you want a "sensiblity" wrt $D_x$ (indeed with a meaning to be precised), it would be better to do it the other way : changing vector $v_i$ into  matrix $(v_i)_{_\times}$... and keeping $D_i$ as a vector.

Comment: I was reading a book, and it says that T is the kinetic energy, so the electric force for a system of N electric tubes moving with velocity $\vec{u}_j$  each one should be  derivative, $$ -2 \left( \sum_j \vec{u}_j \times \vec{D}_j \right)\times \frac{1}{N} \sum_i \vec{u}_i$$ But thats what the author says but he does't prove it